# Is there a feature in Django for saving a history of files uploaded by a user?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have built a Django application that allows a user to upload his/her resume. The resume can be of any format(.pdf, .txt and even .mp4 video). The user also has the option to update the current resume by uploading a new file.

I wish to have a feature wherein the user has the option to go back to his/her history of uploaded resumes to view the old ones.

Django's `FileField` model object only keeps track of the latest upload.
Is there are any existing feature in Django that would help me in easily build a feature wherein a history of uploaded files are maintained?

Comment: You can make a many-to-one relation with another model with a `FileField`, something like `ResumeVersion`.

Comment: so each time a resume is uploaded I need to number it an save it?

Comment: no, you just construct a new `ResumeVersion` object that you relate to the `Resume` object. You can use a timestamp (that is set automatically) to ensure that you order it correctly.

Comment: so every time i need to view the latest resume, I query for the for recent entry in the db? is that correct?